# Obtaining error information when using the Amadeus flight offers price API with python

Tags: python, compiler-errors, amadeus

I have been using the python Amadeus library to access data from flight offer search and flight offers price endpoints. I have received flight information using flight offer search, but when this information on flight offers price, I get the message ClientError: [400] and no further detail on the error. On the Amadeus website there is examples of where further information is provided on what causes the error, is obtaining such information not possible using python?

I am using jupter notebook.

Comment: 400(https://www.howtogeek.com/359267/what-is-a-400-bad-request-error-and-how-can-i-fix-it/) error states that error is in request data sent, mostly requesting API responds with the error details, if not API has to be debugged manually for the error.

Comment: My issue is not with what is causing the error but with the error response given back from the API having less information than the examples on the Amadeus API reference pages online

Answer (score 0):

You can change the log level to get more information. You can find an example in the Python SDK documentation: https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-python#logging--debugging